# How to configure other angular brackets than {{$x}}, maybe [[$x]]?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to configure other than angularjs brackets `{{$fieldname}}` ? Maybe `[[$fieldname]]`. Where can this be configured in angularjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)

you can change default the interpolation markup as below

```
 var app= angular.module('app', []);

 app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! Link to AngularJs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider